# Frobenius method, cant find the roots

Tags: roots, frobenius-method

I am trying to solve this equation with Frobenius method :

$(x^2-x)y''(x) + (1/3) y'(x) + xe^{(x-1)}y(x)=0$

I am trying to find the roots with : $r^2 + (P_0-1) + Q_0 = 0$

And, $P_0 = (1/0!)(1/3x)^{(0)}$ evaluated at $x=0$ but it gives me $1/0$!

I am able to find my $Q_0$ with : $Q_0 = (1/0!)((x-1)e^{(x-1)})^{(0)}$ evaluated at $x=0$ and it gives me $-1/e$.

How am I supposed to find my roots if $P_0 = 1/0$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes but $1/0!(1/0) = 1/0$ no?